# How to input regular expression, in a batch script written for the Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, batch-processing

Below the script counts the files in the source directory and performs different actions based on the count and the filename. If there are two or more files, it exits with a code of 2. If there are no files, it exits with a code of 0. If there's exactly one file, it checks if the filename is "MT569." If it is, the file is copied to the target directory, and the script exits with a code of 1. If the filename is not "MT569," it exits with a code of 3.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "sourceDir=C:\Users\tar\Desktop\inbound"
set "targetDir=C:\Software\components\data\GateIn\in"
set "count=0"

for %%I in ("%sourceDir%\*.*") do (
    set /a "count+=1"
    set "filename=%%~nI"
)

if %count% geq 2 (
    exit /b 2
) else if %count% equ 0 (
    exit /b 0
) else if %count% equ 1 (
    for /f %%A in ('powershell -command "[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('!filename!', 'YourPattern')"') do (
        if %%A equ 1 (
            xcopy /y "%sourceDir%\!filename!.*" "%targetDir%"
            exit /b 1
        ) else (
            exit /b 3
        )
    )
)

endlocal
```

Question - and this is where basically I am stuck and need your help.
Instead of using of filename as "MT569" , I am rather expecting below sort of file.
COLLAT.CONFIDENTIAL.20231013125640.NO-ACCT.416.ISO

Therefor I am trying to use regular expression "COLLAT.CONFIDENTIAL.\d{14}.NO-ACCT.\d{3}.ISO" in my batch script, however In a standard Windows batch script, I think I cannot use regular expressions directly.

Can someone help me fix this issue please?

Thanks,

I don't know the solution

Comment: Windows Batch doesn't support regexes. You can try the underscore wildcard, but it won't specifically match numbers; it matches any single character in a specific location. You could replace `\d{3}` with three underscores to do what you want, as long as you're aware that it would match `123` and `abc` in that location.

Comment: well, seeing as how you're passing the filename to PowerShell for RegEx matching, you're missing the actual pattern in `'YourPattern'`.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you, 
I added below snippet in my script, it didn't work 
 else if %count% equ 1 (
    for /f %%A in ('powershell -command "[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('!filename!', 'COLLAT.CONFIDENTIAL.______________.NO-ACCT.___.ISO')"') do (
        if %%A equ 1 (
            xcopy /y "%sourceDir%\!filename!.*" "%targetDir%"
            exit /b 1
        ) else (
            exit /b 3

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Thanks for your response as mentioned I added it. despite that file is not copied.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry I did not mean to offend.

exam - file format  COLLAT.CONFIDENTIAL.20231013125640.NO-ACCT.416.ISO

long string is used for - 20231013125640.
3 underscores - 416
I specifically need to use windows batch script, can't entirely use powershell.

Comment: You would use regular expressions  by `FINDSTR` utility: `FOR /F "tokens=3 DELIMS=." %%A IN (' DIR /B COLLAT.CONFIDENTIAL.*.NO-ACCT.416.ISO ')  DO (ECHO %%A |FINDSTR /R "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")`. But it has poor usabiliity.

Comment: As an aside: For the `.` characters in the regex to be treated literally, they must be escaped as ``\.``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A streamlined solution:

- It avoids `enabledelayedexpansion` and `(...)` blocks.
- It calls [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, to perform the desired [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) matching via its [`-notmatch` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) and reflects the result in its exit code via an `exit` statement, which `cmd.exe`'s `||` operator can act on.

```bash
@echo off & setlocal

set "sourceDir=C:\Users\tar\Desktop\inbound"
set "targetDir=C:\Software\components\data\GateIn\in"

:: Count the files of interest and save the name of the last file found.
set count=0
for %%f in ("%sourceDir%\*.*") do set /a count+=1 & set "filename=%%~nf"

:: Exit with code 0, if there are no files,
:: and with code 2, if there are 2 or more.
if %count% EQU 0 exit /b 0
if %count% GEQ 2 exit /b 2

:: There is only one file - check if its name matches the regex; 
:: if not, exit with code 3.
powershell -c "if ($env:filename -notmatch '^COLLAT\.CONFIDENTIAL\.\d{14}\.NO-ACCT\.\d{3}\.ISO$') { exit 1 }" || exit /b 3

:: The name matches the regex: copy the file to the destination 
:: and exit with code 1.
xcopy /y "%sourceDir%\%filename%.*" "%targetDir%"
exit /b 1
```

Note:

- As in your code, only the *base* file name, i.e. *without extension* is used (`%%~nf`); if you meant to include the extension, use `%%~nxf`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution to your problem:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

SET /a count=0
FOR %%e IN ("%sourcedir%\COLLAT.CONFIDENTIAL.*.NO-ACCT.*.ISO") DO FOR /f "tokens=3,5delims=." %%b IN ("%%~nxe") DO (
 SET "critical=%%b%%c9"
 FOR /l %%y IN (0,1,9) DO SET "critical=!critical:%%y=!"
 IF NOT DEFINED critical (
  SET "critical=%%b-%%c-"
  IF "!critical:~14,1!" equ "-" IF "!critical:~18!" equ "-" (
   SET /a count +=1
   SET "filename=%%~nxe"
  )
 )
)

ECHO %count% %filename%

GOTO :EOF
```

First, use a filemask to select only those filenames matching your pattern.

Next, tokenise the filename. We need only to check that the two numeric sections are of the correct length and are purely numeric.

Set `critical` to the concatenation of the two filename sections, plus a `9`.

Replace each digit in `critical` with *nothing* (The spare `9` ensures that `critical` does not become *empty* until the very last substitution)

If the result in `critical` is *nothing*, then there were no non-numerics in `critical` to start with, so we need to check that the two lengths are correct.

String `%%b` and `%%c` with some dashes into `critical`. If the 15th and 19th characters of the results are both `-`, then we have lengths of 14 and 3 for `%%b` and `%%c`, and all checks have been passed.

(Note that in `!var:~m,n!` the first character is character "0", hence 14,18 selects the 15th/19th character)